# Copying File In Current Working Directory is Not Working

Tags: java

```
private void copyFile() throws IOException {

    Path destination;
    String currentWorkingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    File fileToCopy = component.getArchiveServerFile();
    if (path.contains(File.separator)) {
        destination = Paths.get(path);
    } else {
        destination = Paths.get(currentWorkingDir + File.separator + path);
    }
    if (!Files.exists(destination)) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(destination);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(fileToCopy, new File(destination.toString()));
}
```

}

Basically what I'm trying to do here is copying a file in some location using the path provided in the class's constructor. The logic is like this:

1. If the path has file separator, I consider it a full path and copy the file at the end.
2. If the path doesn't have file separator, I copy the file in the working directory from which the .exe file was launched.

So far, only the first option works (the full path). For some reason, the working directory option is not working and I can't figure out why.

**UPDATE**: If I just change the following line:

```
String currentWorkingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

to

```
String currentWorkingDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

It works. So I'm guessing the problem is coming from `user.dir`? Maybe at runtime, the folder is already being used and as a result, it can't copy the file into it?

The weird thing is, I don't have any exceptions or error, but nothing happens as well.

**UPDATE 2**: I think the problem here is that I'm trying to copy a file which is embedded in the application (.exe file) that I'm executing during runtime, and java can't copy it while the current working directory is being used by the application.

**UPDATE 3**:

Since this copy method is used in an external library, I had to come up with another way (other than logs) to see the content of system property `user.dir`. So I wrote I little program to create a file and write in it the value return by the property.

To my surprise, the path is not where my application was launched. It was in:

```
C:\Users\jj\AppData\Local\Temp\2\e4j1263.tmp_dir1602852411
```

Which is weird because I launched the program from :

```
C:\Users\jj\workspace\installer\product\target\
```

Any idea why I'm getting this unexpected value for `user.dir`?

Comment: Did you checked where `System.getProperty("user.dir")` points to and if you have write permission?

Comment: There is `Path.isAbsolute()` which should be a more reliable check than considering the file path absolute due to the presence of a `separator`. Why don't you `resolve()` the file name to a given directory `Path`? It would be better than concatenating `String`s in `Paths.get(...)`. If you are using `java.nio`, why not use `File.toPath()` to have only `Path`s after receiving a `File` from somewhere else? And finally, why are you using `FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory` when there is `Files.copy(Path souce, Path target, CopyOption copyOption)`?

Comment: I forgot to ask *What exactly isn't working in the second option?* Wasn't the file created / copied? Was an `Exception` thrown? Was it created or copied to an undesired directory? Could you please add those details to your question?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. As I mentioned in the OP, the second option works when I change `user.dir` to `user.home`. But I have to choose user.dir.